# Option "cores" from package doParallel useless on Windows?

Tags: r, doparallel, parallel-foreach

On a Linux computer, following [**doParallel**'s vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf), I use `doParallel::registerDoParallel()` and then I use `options(cores = N)` where `N` is the number of cores I want to use with `foreach`.

I can verify with `foreach::getDoParWorkers()` that when I change the option `cores`, it automatically changes the number of cores used by `foreach`.

Yet, on Windows 10 (latest versions of R and packages), this option doesn't seem to have any effect as changing its value doesn't change the value of `foreach::getDoParWorkers()` (which is initialized at `3` when calling `doParallel::registerDoParallel()`).

Reproducible example:

```
doParallel::registerDoParallel()
options(cores = 1)
foreach::getDoParWorkers()
options(cores = 2)
foreach::getDoParWorkers()
options(cores = 4)
foreach::getDoParWorkers()
```

Is it a bug? Won't it work on Windows?

**Edit:** I know how to register parallel backends differently. The goal is to use `doParallel::registerDoParallel()` registering once (at the loading of my package) and then use an option to change the number of cores used. This is why I want it to work also on Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer from the maintainer of package **doParallel**, Rich Calaway:

> Windows does not support forking, which is what the parallel (and doParallel) packages use the “cores” argument for. So, on Windows, all “cores” arguments are set to 1. To use multiple cores on Windows with doParallel, use makeCluster to create a multiple worker cluster cl, then registerDoParallel(cl).

So this isn't a bug, but a non-Windows feature, which is a pity.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure it by using both `parallel` and `doParallel` package.

- first create cluster
- register do parallel with that

  ```
  library(parallel)
  library(doParallel)
  cluster <- makeCluster(3)
  registerDoParallel(cluster)
  foreach::getDoParWorkers()
  [1] 3
  ```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question. Please see my edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

What about to stop the cluster and create a new process??

For example:

```
stops<-function(cl,n){
stopCluster(cl)
cl<-makeCluster(n)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

}
```